# computing cos similarity of 2 row vectors, not all pairwise cdists

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have two pandas df trigger and action that contain 25-dimensional feature vectors written in the rows and want the cosine similarity between correspondent rows. The code below produces the 20675 x 20675 matrix of pairwise cosine similarities:

```
trigger.shape
(20675, 25)
action.shape
(20675, 25)
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
result = cdist(trigger, action, metric='cosine')
result.shape
(20675, 20675)
```

I would like to end up with a result matrix that has shape 20675 x 1 where each row is the cosine similarity between the corresponding row vectors from trigger and action.

I've searched and can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute the cosine similarity by yourself.

```
from scipy import lingalg
cosineSim1 = 1 - np.sum(a * b, axis=-1)/(linalg.norm(a,axis=-1) * linalg.norm(b,axis=-1))
```

Test whether you get correct values:

```
from scipy import spatial
cosineSim2 = []
for row_a, row_b in zip(a,b):
    cosineSim2.append(spatial.distance.cosine(row_a, row_b))
np.allclose(cosineSim1, cosineSim2). # Should output True
```

Timing tests:

```
timeit.timeit(func1, number=100)   # computes cosineSim1
0.006364107131958008

timeit.timeit(func2, number=100)  # computes cosineSim2
0.34532594680786133
```

Comment: Btw, `-1` is not limited to `axis`. `-1` means the last element of the list, `-2` means the second from the last etc. By same logic, `-1` is the last axis. You would get same result if you say `axis=1` in this example.